# how to offset an image with php/html?

Tags: php, html, css

My foreach loop in **display.php** which is called from Main.html when a user hits a button is supposed to generate a different image for each num that is passed into it, however it's only displaying one image. Is there a way I can move each image after the first a set amount of pixels to the right or left?

**display.php**

```
<?php
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','draftdb');
    if (!$mysqli)
    die("Can't connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());



    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT display.PICTURE_ID 
    FROM cards  
    INNER JOIN display ON cards.DISPLAY_ID = display.DISPLAY_ID 
    WHERE display.DISPLAY_ID=? AND cards.CARD_TYPE ='rare'" );


    $nums = isset($_POST['nums']) ? $_POST['nums'] : array();
    foreach((array)$nums as $key => $displayid)
    {
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $displayid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($image);
        $stmt->fetch();
        header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
        echo $image; 
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");` directive will force only the first image to be displayed.

Instead write a page that includes a loop of `<img>` tags, with their `src` pointing to this script (pass in an ID or something, so the script prints out the right image).

Comment: +1. If you do this, the images should all show up right next to each other, from left to right, hopefully wrapping when they reach the end of the window (or the parent element). If you want more space between them, use css and the margin property.

Comment: can you give me a proper example of an <img> tag that call my function to return a single element at a time?